# Why is LinkageError Fatal in NonFatal.scala

Tags: scala, error-handling

I was looking at [`scala.util.control.NonFatal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.control.NonFatal$). I can't find the source, but I believe it is something like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.reactivestreams$reactive-streams-tck@1.0.0.RC1@org$reactivestreams$tck$support$NonFatal.java).

They are declaring `LinkageError` as `Fatal` ...

Tomcat (at least last few years I used it) always returned 500 on `catch Throwable`, rather than crashing on certain kinds of errors.  So do many other systems that make a best effort to always return *something* to the client.

So, my end question is when would you use `NonFatal` instead of making a best-effort attempt to provide *some* response?

As an example, now Futures [in Twitter's Future library](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Future.scala) end up not resolving on `NoSuchMethodError` so my `Future` no longer resolves as failed with a `Throwable` but instead throw up the stack (differently from `RuntimeException`).  In fact, in the open source Finagle stack, a `NoSuchMethodError` will cause the client socket connection to close on the client with no 500 http error back to customer.  Customer then thinks 'hmm, network issue maybe ... why did my socket close'

So far, it has caused me nothing but issues and I admit to be a little frustrated, but need to be open to more use cases.  For years, KISS and treating every `Throwable` in the catchall as non fatal has worked, but `NonFatal` is implying there are use-cases where we should do something different.

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/util/control/NonFatal.scala#L1) of `NonFatal` is linked from the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.NonFatal$).

Fatal errors are those from which your **system or the JVM will most likely not recover correctly**, so catching those errors is not a good idea.

The sub-classes of `LinkageError` are: `ClassCircularityError`, `ClassFormatError`, `ExceptionInInitializerError`, `IncompatibleClassChangeError`, `NoClassDefFoundError`, `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, `VerifyError`. These all occur when your class path is broken, there are invalid or binary incompatible class files. It's safe to assume that your entire system is broken if these happen at runtime.

---

To answer the question: You should "let it crash". Always use a `NonFatal` pattern match when you need a catch-all clause. It will also do you the favour and handle **control-flow related exceptions** correctly (e.g. `NonLocalReturnControl`).

---

Note that unlike the old source you link to, `StackOverflowError` is *not* non-fatal any longer, the decision was revised in Scala 2.11 as per [SI-7999](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7999).

Comment: Can I get some clarification.  What is the reasoning to not make a best effort logging the issue and informing your customer it failed?  Last time I hit this in consulting, I came into a team who had wasted a week because they didn't catch Throwable and log it.  For years tomcat has worked just fine catching Throwable and logging it and returning 500 to customers.  Are you suggesting this should change as well?

Comment: And maybe one more question?  You believe we should not be telling customers http 500 and instead just crashing on them?  I truly struggle with going against that as it is our bug and IMHO we should tell them such that they don't' waste time debugging an issue that is not their bug.

Comment: oh, and +1 for taking the time to answer so I upvoted it.  I want to see more answers before I put anything as the best answer